# Go: how to check if a string contains multiple substrings?

Tags: string, go

`strings.Contains(str_to_check, substr)` takes only one argument as the substring to check, how do I check multiple substrings without using `strings.Contains()` repeatedly?

eg. `strings.Contains(str_to_check, substr1, substr2)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can write your own utility function using `strings.Contains()` that can work for multiple sub-strings.

Here's an example that returns Boolean (`true`/`false`) in case of complete / partial match and the total number of matches:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func checkSubstrings(str string, subs ...string) (bool, int) {

    matches := 0
    isCompleteMatch := true

    fmt.Printf("String: \"%s\", Substrings: %s\n", str, subs)

    for _, sub := range subs {
        if strings.Contains(str, sub) {
            matches += 1
        } else {
            isCompleteMatch = false
        }
    }

    return isCompleteMatch, matches
}

func main() {
    isCompleteMatch1, matches1 := checkSubstrings("Hello abc, xyz, abc", "abc", "xyz")
    fmt.Printf("Test 1: { isCompleteMatch: %t, Matches: %d }\n", isCompleteMatch1, matches1)

    fmt.Println()

    isCompleteMatch2, matches2 := checkSubstrings("Hello abc, abc", "abc", "xyz")
    fmt.Printf("Test 2: { isCompleteMatch: %t, Matches: %d }\n", isCompleteMatch2, matches2)
}
```

Output:

```
String: "Hello abc, xyz, abc", Substrings: [abc xyz]
Test 1: { isCompleteMatch: true, Matches: 2 }

String: "Hello abc, abc", Substrings: [abc xyz]
Test 2: { isCompleteMatch: false, Matches: 1 }
```

Here's the live example: https://play.golang.org/p/Xka0KfBrRD

Comment: Good answer, there is also at least 2 other options with using regex and custom scanner - see my answer.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can do this without calling `strings.Contains()` multiple times.

If you know substrings in advance the easiest way to check this with regular expression.  And if a string to check is long and you have quite a few substrings it can be more fast then calling multiple `strings.Contains`

Example https://play.golang.org/p/7PokxbOOo7:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var re = regexp.MustCompile(`first|second|third`)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString("This is the first example"))
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString("This is the second example after first"))
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString("This is the third example"))
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString("This is the forth example"))
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
false
```

If the subs to check are dynamic it may be a bit more difficult to create regex as you need to escape special characters and regex compilation is not fast so `strings.Contains()` may be better in this case though it's better test if your code is performance critical.

**Another good option** could be to write your own scanner that can leverage common prefixes in substrings (*if any*) using [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: Nice one, Alex! Can we impose the checking of all the sub-strings using regex?

Comment: You can if they are in specific order. If they are in arbitrary order you still can but the regex could become pretty complicated for N > 2 as you would need permutation of all possible options - will become messy pretty quickly.

Comment: Great Suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

Another solution would be using a combination of `regexp` and `suffixarray`. From the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/index/suffixarray):

> Package suffixarray implements substring search in logarithmic time using an in-memory suffix array.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "index/suffixarray"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(contains("first secondthird", "first", "second", "third"))
    fmt.Println(contains("first secondthird", "first", "10th"))
}

func contains(str string, subStrs ...string) bool {
    if len(subStrs) == 0 {
        return true
    }
    r := regexp.MustCompile(strings.Join(subStrs, "|"))
    index := suffixarray.New([]byte(str))
    res := index.FindAllIndex(r, -1)
    exists := make(map[string]int)
    for _, v := range subStrs {
        exists[v] = 1
    }
    for _, pair := range res {
        s := str[pair[0]:pair[1]]
        exists[s] = exists[s] + 1
    }
    for _, v := range exists {
        if v == 1 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

(In [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8MJQ6t1tSV))

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    listStrings := []string{"d", "x"}
    for _,value:= range listStrings {
        if strings.Contains("mystring", value) {
            fmt.Println("Contains")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> [H]ow do I check multiple substrings without using `strings.Contains()` repeatedly?

Not at all. You *have* to call Contains repeatedly.

Comment: noted, i was just wondering if i can use less code to achieve this (in Go)

Comment: @jm33_m0 Write a util function doing just this, and from there on you can do it with "less" code by calling this util function.

Comment: @Volker, no you have not to. There are few other options - see my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok Of course. Throwing regexps at any problem is a fine solution.

Comment: @Volker, not at any problem. But in some cases it can be easier to code and have better performance. So I'm not getting your sarcasm.