# Checking if a string contains a substring contained in a slice in Go

Tags: go

I have an array of substrings and a slice of strings. I want to check if the string contains any of the substrings in the mySliceOfSubstrings slice.

```
mySliceOfSubstrings := []string{"hello", "world"}
mySliceOfStringsToCheck := []string{"hello mars", "hey mars"}
```

Is there a better way of doing it the below way of putting a loop inside a loop?

```
for _, string := range mySliceOfStringsToCheck {

     for _, substring := range mySliceOfSubstrings {
          result := strings.Contains(string, substring)

     }  

}
```

What if I wanted to check the string against two different slice of substrings?

Comment: you have slices of strings -- what is a "splice" of strings?

Comment: @JimB sorry have edited

Comment: Using an regexp is another way to do it, but it may or may not be better depending on the usage.

Comment: There really isn't a better way of doing this, since (in the case of attempting alternation in a regex) you might have regex-special chars that would need escaping and anything you'd try wouldn't be any faster anyway AND attempting this as e.g. a []byte compare instead of chars might capture the wrong thing in the case of oddball multichar non-ASCII strings.

So the regexp case is probably slower and equally complex thanks to escapes and having to generate the regexp and the []byte case could generate false positives.  For bigger cases, you could look at creating indices of terms, though.

Comment: You may be able to speed things up depending on info you have not provided - eg. whether the strings or sub-strings change (often).  For example, join the strings to search into one long string (sep. by an unused char if there is one) or put the substrings in a trie.

Do you want the location of the first found sub-string or just know whether any one is found or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go: how to check if a string contains multiple substrings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131996/go-how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-multiple-substrings)

Answer (score 0):

Unless the size of data is very large and you're looking for algorithmic improvements over the O(N^2) solution you currently have, your code is fine.

For very large data you could consider using some more sophisticated data structures. For example, Go has the https://golang.org/pkg/index/suffixarray package that would let you take your slice of strings to check, preprocess it, and then perform substring lookups in logarithmic time.